# Sort Element of array on the basis of another array in lexical order by using just sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, data-structures

Suppose We have two arrays parameter and order ,I want to place the order array elements first and sorted order of all other elements in the resultant.

I don't want to make use of order array during sorting.
and also want to use sort function.

```
let parameter = ['Door', 'fjjfh','Container Number','jdjfr', 'Cases', 'hello', "hi", 'Items/sort']

let order = ['Door', 'Container Number', 'Cases', 'Items/sort']

Output ->['Door', 'Container Number', 'Cases', 'Items/sort','fjjfh','hello','hi','jdjfr']
```

Comment: What order do you want the `order` array elements in? The order they have in the original array, or `order`?

Comment: same as it is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check whether each of the items being sorted is in the `order` array and give preference to the one that is (or to their relative position if they both are), see comments:

```js
let parameter = ['Door', 'fjjfh','Container Number','jdjfr', 'Cases', 'hello', "hi", 'Items/sort'];
let order = ['Door', 'Container Number', 'Cases', 'Items/sort'];

// Wanted: ["Door", "Container Number", "Cases", "Items/sort","fjjfh","hello","hi","jdjfr"]

parameter.sort((a, b) => {
    const apos = order.indexOf(a);
    const bpos = order.indexOf(b);
    if (apos !== -1) {
        // `a` is in the `order` array
        if (bpos === -1) {
            // `b` isn't, put `a` first
            return -1;
        }
        // Both are, put them in the order they have in `order`
        return apos - bpos;
    } else if (bpos !== -1) {
        // `b` is in the `order` array, `a` isn't; `b` comes first
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Neither is in the `order` array, put them in lexicographical order
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
});
console.log(parameter);
```

If you were sorting a **truly massive** array this way and/or if `order` were **truly massive**, you might want to create a `map` of the positions in `order` before starting so you don't have to traverse `order` linearly for each position lookup:

```js
let parameter = ['Door', 'fjjfh','Container Number','jdjfr', 'Cases', 'hello', "hi", 'Items/sort'];
let order = ['Door', 'Container Number', 'Cases', 'Items/sort'];

// Wanted: ["Door", "Container Number", "Cases", "Items/sort","fjjfh","hello","hi","jdjfr"]

const orderMap = new Map(order.map((value, index) => [value, index]));
parameter.sort((a, b) => {
    const apos = orderMap.get(a);
    const bpos = orderMap.get(b);
    if (apos !== undefined) {
        // `a` is in the `order` array
        if (bpos === undefined) {
            // `b` isn't, put `a` first
            return -1;
        }
        // Both are, put them in the order they have in `order`
        return apos - bpos;
    } else if (bpos !== undefined) {
        // `b` is in the `order` array, `a` isn't; `b` comes first
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Neither is in the `order` array, put them in lexicographical order
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
});
console.log(parameter);
```

But you don't need to bother for small or medium-sized arrays.